# using current year in string to date function

Tags: mysql

The year is expected to be picked as current year instead of the 00 year as shown below.

```
mysql> select str_to_date('Jul 15 12:12:51', '%b %e %T');
+--------------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('Jul 15 12:12:51', '%b %e %T') |
+--------------------------------------------+
| 0000-07-15 12:12:51                        |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

Expected result:

```
| 2013-07-15 12:12:51                        |
```

Comment: why does mysql give year '0000' instead of '1970' like many other systems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that's intended. Quoting the [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

> Unspecified date or time parts have a value of 0, so incompletely
>   specified values in str produce a result with some or all parts set to
>   0. [...]  “Zero” dates or dates with part values of 0 are permitted unless the SQL mode is set to disallow such values.

It's easy to fix, btw:

```
select str_to_date(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), ' ', 'Jul 15 12:12:51'), '%Y %b %e %T');
-- July, 15 2013 12:12:51+0000
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, ugly, but works:

```
select str_to_date(concat('Jul 15, ', year(now()), ' 12:12:51'), '%b %e, %Y %T');
```